# Unable to use React.RefObject with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am porting this class module [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/30q3mzjv91?module=%2Fsrc%2FOutsideAlerter.js) to typescript but i can't set it right the definition of the object reference.

I defined the reference holder as:

```
private wrapperRef:React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
```

The original handler had to be changed so it uses current property, has this:

```
if (this.wrapperRef.current && !this.wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
  alert('You clicked outside of me!');
}
```

but `this.wrapperRef.current` always comes `undefined`.

What i am doing wrong?

Here my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-breeze-z9jq0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't [creating or setting your ref properly](https://css-tricks.com/working-with-refs-in-react/). In a class component, you create the ref with `React.createRef()`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.wrapperRef = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
}
```

And then assign its value by passing it directly to the `ref` property of some element.

```
render() {
  return <div ref={this.wrapperRef}>{this.props.children}</div>;
}
```

Now it should automatically set `this.wrapperRef.current` after the first render. You don't need the `setWrapperRef` method at all.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-grass-8d22l)